# How to get the equivalent data format of curl -T --upload-data option from <input type="file"/> using JavaScript in browser?

Tags: javascript, curl, filereader

curl has [-T, --upload-file](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-T) option to "transfer the specified local file to the remote URL".

```
curl -v "http://some/data/consumer" -XPOST -T "some/file/name"
```

How can I get the equivalent data of a file using `curl -T`, from `<input type="file" />` using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to access the data from javascript, e.g through a data-view, then you can use the [`Blob.arrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) method, which will return a Promise resolving to an ArrayBuffer. Since the *File* interface inherits from *Blob*, this method is also available on File objects directly.

```js
document.getElementById('inp').onchange = async function(evt) {
  const buf = await this.files[0].arrayBuffer();
  console.log( buf.byteLength );
  const view = new Uint8Array(buf, 0, 4); // create a view of 4 first bytes
  console.log(view);
};
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inp">
```

*Note that this method may require a polyfill in older browsers.*

---

But if what you wish is simply to send that File as binary to a server, then `XHR` and `fetch` accept Blob as request body:

```js
// using XHR
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', url);
xhr.send(input.files[0]);

// using fetch
fetch(url, { method: "POST", body: inp.files[0] } );

// using axios
axios.post(url, inp.files[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To clarify a bit more, the reason I posted the question and the answer by myself was that there wasn't any document specifying the format `curl -T "filename"` transfers its data and thus specifying which datatype should be used when we "POST" the same data with JavaScript. Your first answer seems valid one though as you mentioned [its browser compatibility is fairly bad](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35229) right now. (I now realized why I didn't try your solution before posting this question.)

Comment: @LeeHanKyeol yes it's only for recent browsers, but it can be polyfilled really easily (your answer almost got it). So better use that and polyfill for older browsers. And post(arraybuffer) or post(blob) will produce the same requests, so you don't even need that polyfill nor a FileReader, just post the File directly like in my last example.

Comment: @Kalido  Tried it and got it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and read the file with [`readAsArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) method.

```js
const readBlob = file =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => {
      resolve(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = reject;
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file); // THIS
  });
```

Then you can send the request, say with axios, like this.

```js
const blob = await readBlob(...);
axios.post('http://some/data/consumer', blob);
```

Answer (score 0):

Little script i created, Using Node js: locally upload file POST request to a REST API en-point: hope it helps if anyone looking to upload a file with "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data". you need required dependencies http or https/request-promise-native/fs:

```js
const https = require('https');
const rq = require('request-promise-native');
const fs = require('fs');

const url = "<API_url>"
const Agent = new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true , maxSockets :3 });
const user_name= "<provide_username>";
const user_password = "<provide_user_password_or_api_key>";
var user_info = btoa(`${user_name}` + ':' + `${user_password}`);   //base64 conversion, user_password can be API key as well.

const request = rq.defaults({
    headers:    
        {                                       
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + `${user_info}`
        },
    agent: Agent,   
});

const readStream = fs.createReadStream("./test_file.txt"); //read file from local

async function  uploadattachment() {
    try { 
        const vurl = `${url}`
        writeLog(vurl)
        const opt = { 
                    url:vurl,                                           
                    method:"POST",
                    headers:{
                        "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"
                    },
                    formData : {
                        "attachment" : readStream
                    }
                }
        const responseBody = await request({...opt,         
                });
        const request_response = JSON.parse(responseBody); 
        console.log("upload request Response :", request_response);
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        throw e
    }
}    
uploadattachment();
```